# Android Studio 1.4: drawable-v21 ignored when using "File/New/Vector Asset" option

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, drawable

This is my first SO question so please don't eat me alive... Here's my problem:

I've imported few icons via Android Studio 1.4's new option - `New/Vector Asset`. As you know it lets you easily import and use vector drawables and creates pngs for compatibility with APIs <21. It puts the pngs in folders `app/build/generated/res/pngs/debug/drawable-<density>` (mdpi, ldpi, hdpi etc). It also generates the `-v21` versions of all the folders and puts the vector drawable .xmls there.

The problem started, when I wanted to add ripple effect to one of the icons. I've put the .... ripple-less version into my `res/drawable` folder. It looked like this:

**drawable/ic_settings.xml**

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
<path
    android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:pathData="M12,15.5A3.5,3.5 ...blablabla notimportatnt"/>
</vector>
```

Then I wanted to add ripple to the icon in API >21. So to the folder `res/drawable-v21` I added this drawable:

**drawable-v21/ic_settings.xml**

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:color="?android:colorControlHighlight">
<item>
    <vector
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0">
        <path
            android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:pathData="M12,15.5A3.5,3.5 0,0....blah blah blah"/>
    </vector>
</item>
</ripple>
```

Now, when I run the app under API 21, instead of using resources from `drawable-v21` it uses a drawable from `app/build/generated/res/pngs/debug/drawable-xxhdpi-v21`automatically generated based on the file in `res/drawable`. So no ripple.

When I tried to remove the ripple-less file from `res/drawable/`, the ripple comes back in API 21, but of course the app crashes in APIs<21

Then I tried to put ripple version of the icon to the `res/drawable` folder, hoping that gradle would automatically generate the pngs. Nope - `<ripple>` tag prevents gradle from generating pngs and the app crashes <21.

Anyone stumbled upon this kind of problem? Any idea how to add ripple to the icon?

Have a good day!

Comment: I was just about to ask the same question..

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I kinda found the solution.

In folder `res/drawable` I left only the vectors that can and should be automatically converted to pngs - so only plain normal icons without ripple. Then in `drawable_v21` I've put the ripple version of drawable and renamed it -  `ic_settings_ripple.xml`. I've created a new folder `layout-v21`and duplicated my layout, but instead of `ic_settings.xml` i used `ic_settings_ripple.xml`.

So now under API<21 the app uses ripple-less png generated by gradle, and at API>=21 there is an alternative layout, that uses ripple version of one of the icon.